# Pivot calculated field of variation

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, calculator, pivot-chart, column

I want to create a pivot graph that shows the variation (%) in number of road accidents from year to year+1. I need it to be **pivot** because I want it to be refreshable if data change.
My data is a list of accidents (1 record = 1 accident) and one of their attributes (columns) is the year, as shown in the example below:

Data used

| Record id | Year |
| --- | --- |
| accident 1 | 2011 |
| accident 2 | 2012 |
| accident 3 | 2011 |
| accident 4 | 2012 |
| accident 5 | 2012 |
| accident 6 | 2013 |
| accident 7 | 2014 |
| accident 8 | 2014 |
| accident 9 | 2015 |
| accident 10 | 2016 |

My guess is that I need to create a calculated field in the pivot, but I can't figure how to get this specific field.
The pivot table and the pivot graph, based on the data shown above, should ideally look like this:

Target pivot table

| Year | number of accidents | number of accidents compared to previous year (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 2 | nd |
| 2012 | 3 | 50% |
| 2013 | 1 | -67% |
| 2014 | 2 | 100% |
| 2015 | 1 | -50% |
| 2016 | 1 | 0% |

Target pivot graph

[image: Target pivot graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two helper columns to your data. Column C counts the number of accidents which match the row's year. Column D counts the number of accidents from the prior year.

```
Cell C2 formula: =COUNTIF(B:B,B2)

Cell D2 formula: =COUNTIF(B:B,B2-1)
```

Drag 'em down.

The Calculated field formula in the pivot is then:

```
= (Current_Year_Total -Prior_Year_Total )/Prior_Year_Total
```

You'll just need to decide how you want to treat year-0 and adjust the chart if you don't want to display 2011.

[image]